# illegal character in jsonp response

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, jsonp, illegal-characters

Hi i am doing an exercise where I am trying to scrape content of nytimes website using javascript/ajax.

In order to send cross domain ajax request I am using a proxy server that returns me jsonp response with nytimes website content.

But since that html content has some charaters (single quotes) which throws "Illegal Character" error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://json-proxy.jgate.de/?callback=callback&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F"></script>
<script>
function callback(obj) {
 alert(obj);
}
</script>
```

What could be a possible solution to this error?
And what are other alternatives to solve this?

Thanks

(p.s. This question was asked to one my friends in his interview)

Update: Here is yahoo pipes link for the same.
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=748e37c218ed0747d0b868ae8eafefa6&_render=json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo pipes fixed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the characters on the server.

```
callback('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W...etc.') // notice the \"-//W
```

Instead of:

```
callback('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W...etc.') // which will eventually create an error
```

Escape all the special characters like */*, **\**, *"*, **'** to */*, *\* ...

Comment: I don't have access to that proxy server. I found that server online.

Comment: There is a bug with your first server which makes it output unusable JSON for the site youre trying to get. But the Yahoo Pipes JSONP works: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=748e37c218ed0747d0b868ae8eafefa6&_render=json&_callback=callback